# WSE X509 Certificate Tool - where's the exe?

Tags: .net, certificate, x509certificate

I'm having a problem with accessing the private key in a certificate from my .net application.

I want to check permissions on my certificate using the WSE 3.0 certificate tool.

The problem is when I install it, I only have access to a DLL (Microsoft.Web.Services3.dll) and a licening document.

It's installed here: C:\Program Files\Microsoft WSE\v3.0

And I downloaded the msi from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6545

What on Earth is up?

FYI: I want to do this: http://benoit808.wordpress.com/2008/10/31/cryptographicexception-the-handle-is-invalid/

Comment: Of course, I find it as soon as I post to Stack Overflow. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14089

Comment: Are you aware that WSE is obsolete and should only be used if there are no other choices at all?

Comment: No, please tell me! Any info would be appreciated. I'm new to this certificate stuff and would love to be pointed in the right direction!

Comment: WSE was replaced by WCF over six years ago. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/wcf/info for some good links about WCF. Also, FYI, it's worth using version 4.0 or 4.5 of .NET for WCF applications, as the configuration has been far, far, simpler in those releases.

Comment: Ah okay, I'm actually not writing services, but am just trying to configure certificates using the WSE tool. Do you know of a better tool to set permissions on Private Keys of Certificates? Thanks for the input!

Comment: Or do you know of any diagnostic tool I can use to trouble shoot problematic certificates? Specifically in Windows Server 2003

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about WSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer pretty much immediately after posting the question (derrrr...).

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14089